Selenium returns looked up element unreliably
I got stuck.. so many hours.. looked up hundreds of questions & answers here..
I want to grep data from a banks product website, e.g. "Delta" from:
https://wertpapiere.ing.de/Investieren/Derivat/DE000HS2JL06

(link will be dead on 17.09.2024 as product is going to end then)
delta.text should be -0,0193
First attempt:
delta = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[text()=\'Delta\']/following-sibling::td')

works sometimes.. mostly not.. for what reason? It could be the case as "Delta" appears 10 times on the site but then:
delta = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[text()=\'Delta\']/[5]following-sibling::td') 

should solve the issue but it doesn't.
Another try:
delta = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//td[contains(text(), "Delta")]/following-sibling::td') 

should work but doesn't either.
The attempt with the full path should solve the issue:
delta = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/main/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/sh-derivative-greeks/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]')

but the element can't be found; I assume because of the dynamic IDs the site is generating.
Does anyone have the decisive tip?
Thanks so much!
Chris

Information in that page is being fed via XHR calls to various API endpoints. You can inspect those endpoints in browser's Dev Tools -> Network tab.
Here is how you can get that particular delta value:
import requests
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_colwidth', None)

headers = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'
}

df = pd.json_normalize(requests.get('https://component-api.wertpapiere.ing.de/api/v1/derivative/greeks/DE000HS2JL06', headers=headers).json())
print(df[[x for x in df.columns if x not in ['description.value']]])

Result in terminal:
isin    isEmpty isVisible   description.label   delta.value delta.formatString  delta.formatType    delta.label gamma.value gamma.formatString  gamma.formatType    gamma.label theta.value theta.formatString  theta.formatType    theta.label vega.value  vega.formatString   vega.formatType vega.label  rho.value   rho.formatString    rho.formatType  rho.label   omega.value omega.formatString  omega.formatType    omega.label labels.title    labels.noInformationAvailable
0   DE000HS2JL06    False   True    Erklärung der Griechen  -0.0193 0,0.00[00]  Number  Delta   0.0003  0,0.00[00]  Number  Gamma   -0.003  0,0.00[00]  Number  Theta   0.0139  0,0.00[00]  Number  Vega    -0.0382 0,0.00[00]  Number  Rho -8.8416 0,0.00  Number  Omega (Hebel)   Griechen    Keine Informationen vorhanden

Requests documentation can be found here.
EDIT: If you prefer Selenium:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,1080")

with webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options) as driver:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
    driver.get('https://wertpapiere.ing.de/Investieren/Derivat/DE000HS2JL06')
    delta_value = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//div[@class="sh-derivative-greeks"]//tr[@name="delta"]//td[@class="value"]'))).get_attribute('innerHTML')
    print(delta_value)

Result in terminal:
-0,0193

Selenium documentation can be found here.

Impressive, thank you so much! I prefer the pandas style, awesome the pd.json_normalize solution.
So in the Selenium solution, the wait.until is needed as the XHR calls need some time and that is the reason why I mostly didn't get the result, right?

Indeed, Selenium needs to wait for that element to be fully loaded in page. Glad it helped you @ChristianLinden, don't forget to mark the answer as Accepted (green checkmark under voting buttons).

bless you @Barry the Platipus

Where did you find that URL: https://component-api.wertpapiere.ing.de/api/v1/derivative/greeks/DE000HS2JL06 ?
I find the https://component-api.wertpapiere.ing.de
but nowhere the rest of the URL.

As explained, in browser's Dev Tools - Network tab, under XHR calls.

ah jep, some down.. sorry, never used that before.. found it =)
blessings^2 !
